# Determine a fourth point on a plane given three points and a condition

Tags: geometry

I have the blue, yellow and orange dots defined by *(x,y,z)* and I'd like to determine the cross point of the blue lines. Getting its *x* and *y* are trivial (I know which is the left/lower extremum and that they do differ).

However, I'm stuck on getting the *z* value. I can see that I need to **somehow** relate the *z* of the blue and the yellow to the *z* of the orange.

How can I get there?

[image]

Comment: Can't make any sense of your question. You tell about three points, draw four and compute a fifth ?!

Comment: @YvesDaoust I'm sorry if it wasn't obvious. Let me clarify. There are three points: blue, yellow and orange. The fourth I'm computing is the crossing between the blue lines (that are parallel with x and y axis). Please let me know if I can elaborate even better.

Comment: You should discard the gray one.

Comment: Use this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(geometry)#Method_2 and draw the value of $z$ from those of $x, y$. It is also possible to use an equation of the form $z=ax+by+c$ and solve the $3\times3$ system.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Now I see what confused you. Image corrected and rotated for visual improvement. As for the formula(s) on wiki - I'll be doing those operations on a low level computing system so avoiding matrices as long as possible is preferred. I liked the cross-product method (since I already have the normal of the plane precomputed) **but** I can't figure out how to get the constant d in the formula... Hints?

Comment: The use of matrices is immaterial. As the link says, use any nonzero value for $d$. But you should have said that you had the normal, there's a shortcut.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Sorry. Wasn't aware of the significance of it. Now that we know I have the normal - the $ax+by+cz=d$ needs a specific d, not just any d, right? Or am I confusing myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation of the plane is

$$n_x(x-x_0)+n_y(y-y_0)+n_z(z-z_0)=0$$ where $n$ is the normal vector.

Then

$$z=z_0-\frac{n_x(x-x_0)+n_y(y-y_0)}{n_z}.$$

Comment: I think I start to see it. I take the yellow point to be $(x_0 y_0 z_0)$  and the cross will be at $x y z$, of which I only lack $z$, right? Very neat.